# ASP.NET Profile Data Cached?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

Does the ASP.NET SQL Profile Provider use caching? I mean if I pull data from the profile for a user will it hit the DB for each request?

I'm looking for a setting or any information on this. I had thought I read it would use cookies but I can't find this now.

Edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478953.aspx describes process as

When called by SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValues, aspnet_Profile_GetProperties performs the following actions:

1. Queries the aspnet_Applications table to convert the application name input to it into an application ID.
2. Queries the aspnet_Users table to convert the user name input to it into a user ID.
3. Queries the aspnet_Profile table for the PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString, and PropertyValuesBinary fields for the specified user.
4. Updates the user's last activity date in the aspnet_Users table with the current date and time.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

> When your application runs, ASP.NET
>   creates a ProfileCommon class, which
>   is a dynamically generated class that
>   inherits the ProfileBase class. The
>   dynamic ProfileCommon class includes
>   properties created from the profile
>   property definitions you specify in
>   your application configuration. An
>   instance of this dynamic ProfileCommon
>   class is then set as the value of the
>   Profile property of the current
>   HttpContext and is available to pages
>   in your application.

It appears that the Profile object is attached to the current HttpContext of the request.  So, unless you create a new HttpContext, the profile data is loaded and stored here on first request.

**EDIT** - Allen brought up some good points for some clarification here -> the profile data is queried on each HttpRequest (e.g. when a new HttpContext is created).  But within each request, calls to the profile provider for different properties do not keep hitting the DB, only on the first call.

Comment: This link describes the process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478953.aspx. It does not mention caching.

Comment: Every request is going to get a new HttpContext.Current, so unless they specifically cache the data in session, the default profile provider will be going to the database for every request

Comment: @Allen - That is what I said - this answer shows that for each request, the data is loaded once but it does not hit the database for each profile value queried on a single HTTP request (HttpContext).  If this is not clear, I would welcome suggested edits.

Comment: Ah I thought by "Unless you create a new httpcontext", you thought that a new httpcontext was not created for each request.  Also when you said "the profile data is loaded and stored here on first request", I thought you meant http request.  My bad :)

Comment: @allen - no sweat, I added an edit for clarification, does that help clear it up a little for those following behind us?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no

The provider uses "caching" once per request that accesses the profile data.  If you don't access profile data during any given request, it isn't queried.  However, if you access profile data several times during one request (and don't update it) then its only queried once.

The important takeaway is this: if you access profile data on every request, then asp.net is querying the database once per request for your profile data!.

To specifically answer your question: *"If I pull data from the profile for a user will it hit the DB for each **[http]** request?"*  **Yes, it will hit the database each time.**

You could probably build your own provider that does some form of session based caching so you're not always calling the database to lookup your users profile data.  Here is a great article on the topic: **[Optimizing ASP.NET Profiles Performance](http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/08/optimizing-asp-net-profiles-performance/)**